# Creating a view model with an object or properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating my first MVC project, and was curious as to which is the correct way to expose my Code First Entity Classes to my view model. I have a entity class like so:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateAdded { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Is it better to pass in the object, or pass in the a new class of the properties?

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    Product myProduct { get; set; }
}

public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As the answers already given show, this is not a constructive question. One approach is not objectively better than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to go with the second option. It's generally **bad practice** to use your database classes as models. What your first option essentially does is just that, except it wraps it inside another *pointless* class.

What I'd do though, is have them both implement an **interface**, that way if you ever want to change it, just change the interface, then both instances can be changed.

```
public class ProductViewModel : IProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One advantage of Entity Framework is the ability to use plain objects as entities. These objects arguably make ideal models - providing a model layer on top of them *also* involves wrapping entities in "pointless" classes...

Comment: @DanJ Then there's no separation between the DTOs and the presentation layer.

Comment: The View Model *is* the separation between the DTOs and the presentation layer. I think we may be defining "model" differently.

Comment: What if I wanted to have a ViewModel that was comprised of two different types of data. Say I wanted to use the IProduct interface, and I wanted to use an IComment Interface to return the product Information and comments. Would the correct way be to interface both of thee into a view model class then pass that to the view?

Comment: @DanJ Model != View Model. Not in the case of Entity Framework anyway. It's bad terminology. Database Classes and View Models would be better, it's not a good idea for them to be the same thing.

Comment: @ios85 Then you'd build what's called a Composite View Model, it would have a `ProductModel` called `Product` and a `CommentModel` property called `Comment`. No interfaces needed on the composite view model.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely go with the second option. It provides a clear separation from your domain model (entity) and your view model. Separating these models is important because:

- You have two very distinct types of concerns to address

  - Your domain deals with domain logic, actual business processes involved in managing your application's data.
  - Your view is focused on view logic, presenting a good user interface for interacting with that data.
- You can separate the development efforts of your domain and interface layers. You want to minimize the impact that small changes in one layer have on your other layers.

Sure in this example it's kind of trivial, but it will be very important as you build more logic into your view.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to pass in the entity class as a whole. That way if the class ever changes, you will not have to update the properties in your ViewModel.